# Draw many matplotlib scatter plots in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to have several scatter plots (one for each email address).
Is it possible to use my existing code, working for one email, in a for loop and generate many plots?

I saw some examples, but none were using the scatter method.

My current code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.scatter(raw_df[raw_df["email"] == "email@gmail.com"]["x"],
            raw_df[raw_df["email"] == "email@gmail.com"]["y"],
           )
plt.axvline(x=max(raw_df[raw_df["email"] == "email@gmail.com"]["z"]), color="r")
```

The kind of thing I would like to have:

```py
for email in list_of_unique_emails[:10]:
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.scatter(raw_df[raw_df["email"] == email]["x"],
            raw_df[raw_df["email"] == email]["y"],
           )
    plt.axvline(x=max(raw_df[raw_df["email"] == email]["z"]), color="r")
```

Comment: How do you want them displayed? Are all the points on the same axes? Or are you saving each individual graph to a file? Or are you talking multiple plots (axes or sub-figures) on the same figure? If you try your code, why isn't it working for you?

Comment: Right now, every plots go in the same figure, which is not what I want. 
What I want is have a unique figure for each email.

Comment: Just call `plt.figure()` at the beginning of your loop.